# Error code 80070003 and 80004005 when attemting to play music

Tags: music, lumia-520, xbox-music, micro-sd

I was given my Nokia Lumia 520 a while ago (around 3 months) as a gift and it was horrible to start with but after a while i got used to it and its ok everything works, except for the fact if i put my phone down somewhere it turned off as there was a problem with the battery (which i have yet to be fixed because i don't have the money)

Anyway i recently swapped from my 2gb sd card to 64gb (i tried with a 32gb as well but that didn't fix the problem) and since then only one artist has been able to play without getting the Error 80070003 code and a lot of the music i had on before swapping SD cards and it worked just fine. I noticed that when i tried to re-sync the songs to check they weren't corrupt an error came up on the windows phone app thing saying 'something happened we didn't expect error 80004005'.

Is there anyway to fix this? (its a micro sd)

Also when i tried to delete the working artist from my phone it asked if i wanted to delete but then 'copying' came up at the top, what is the phone trying to do?

Comment: How did you resync the music? Is this music you've bought in the store, or transferred from your computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps ;

1.) Go to Link:-

http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Pool-of-Knowledge/Nokia-Windows-Phone-8-App-Updates/m-p/1640082#M242

and scan the Audio and install it and switch off the phone.

2.) Go to Music + Videos and click Music . Go to Songs Section there u can see a duplicate files created for same song i.e; eg:-

Song A -- 1st Song

Song A -- 2nd Song

The 1st song will not play will throw error  80070003. However the 2nd Song may play fine. So you can delete all the 1st Songs and then retain the 2nd One and this may fix the prob. But before deleting confirm you are deleting the erroneous file.

Answer (score 1):

In my Lumia 525 had same problem what I did is just restarted my phone and started music app and the same songs played well.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Error : 80070003

You need to move all your songs onto your pc in a folder via usb or card reader. Then connect your Windows Phone to the pc and move all of your songs to the SD card in the music folder. Your songs may be duplicate in the app, but restarting your cell will fix this and you will no longer receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all your songs onto your PC in a folder via USB or card reader. 
Select all the files. Push the right button in the mouse and select PROPERTIES.
Select the DETAILS tag an erase ALL the contents in TITLE
Then connect your Windows Phone to the PC and move all of your songs to the SD card in the music folder and restart your cell.

Answer (score 0):

No need to format SD card. Just Remove it( using settings ), then go to music you will still see list of songs, select all delete them. Then delete all history (recently played etc.) turn off your phone, insert SD card then turn it on. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

believe me its gonna work:
This error happens when you change memory card.
simple solution is:
Just clear the recent played list in music player which shows albums from previous sd card

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to format your SD card. Just open the music player, select all songs and delete. Then load the songs again. If one song isn't playing, select that and delete. This worked for me.